Documentary about people who torture
Looking for a British documentary, around 2005-2010, possibly made by BBC.
It was a controversial piece where they interview a number of torturers who are free men today. They even manage to film an attack on of them which was committed by the son of one of his victims. 
A South-african who tortured NAACP members tell a harrowing tale of the man who remained defiant even as they burned him alive.
The documentary goes deeper and they learn that the only way to lessen the pain  is to remain defiant and keep your torturers respect throughout. They all agree on this. 
There was a subtle song at one point that was very beautiful: "Don't ask me to forgive you- I'm not the only one." or something very like it.

On topic of torturers, OP might also be interested in 2012 documentary "The Act of Killing" http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2375605/

I think it's We Have Ways Of Making You Talk, which was broadcast on Tuesday, 5 April at 2100BST on BBC Two. 
Basic Summary:

Filmed in France, Israel, USA, Algeria, Argentina, Uruguay, South
  Africa and the UK, this disturbing and candid BBC documentary explores
  the history of modern interrogation techniques and the rise of modern
  torture using revealing interviews with state interrogators and state
  torturers.

From a BBC News article on the documentary, "The Truth About Torture";

During the apartheid era in South Africa, Gideon Nieuwoudt, one of
  South Africa's most notorious torturers, used a range of techniques on
  his ANC victims and retains a philosophical perspective.
"It's like a piano: you make use of the black notes and the white
  notes to make a sweet melody," he says.
He has no doubt the beatings he inflicted on detainees forced them to
  talk: "The people will never give you anything without torture, that I
  can assure you."
Former colleague Paul Van Vuuren lost count of the number of people he
  tortured under apartheid, but is still proud of his skills.
"There are all these movies about Rambo and stuff where they put
  electricity on his bodies and he's not talking. That's bullshit. There
  is no-one in the world; I haven't yet seen one guy that don't talk. I
  can take anyone on and make them talk, that's no problem."
Mr Van Vuuren, who was part of a hit squad snatching activists from
  the townships, had to remove any emotional connection with his victim.
"I can't say I am sorry because then I am lying. At that stage he was
  an object and we had to extract information out of him and we would do
  it to the best of our ability."
A sense of moral righteousness also eases the path to torture. Mr
  Nieuwoudt claims he was following God's orders by using torture to
  maintain the apartheid regime. But he, like many torturers, chose to
  keep his vocation a secret from his family.

Full documentary available here:  (Youtube playlist in 9 parts)
